# Advices on multiplayer implementation

Tags: c#, multiplayer, monogame, server, udp

I am developing a top down shooter and my singleplayer is pratically finished so now I want to move on to develop multiplayer but I have some questions and I am seeking for some advices.

In my game a match is constituted by a character(two in a multiplayer match) , monsters, projectiles, boosts and spawn points.

Here is my initial solution:

Characters- Send to the game server my character(position, if it´s dead or not,currentHealth,etc) and receive the other player character from the server. Thinking about using UDP because I want real time positions

Monsters- My strategy for this one is having the server randomly choosing one of players´computer to handle the spawn of the monsters .The list of monsters is sent to the server and the other player gets it. Thinking about using TCP because a lost package would imply that the round will have less monsters than it should have

Projectiles- When a player clicks the left button to shoot a projectile, the input is sent to the server. This means that the projectiles list would be instanciated in the server and both players will have to get it from it. 99% sure I will use UDP because a lost projectile wouldn´t have a major impact on the match.

Boosts- Probably the same strategy as the monsters. Pretty sure I will be using TCP because if the boost doesn´t spawn in that round it completely alters the match.

I am looking for critics to the strategies I am planning to implement as well as some advices

Comment: The StackExchange Q&A format isn't great for open-ended feedback. What it handles better is focused problem-solving. Is there a specific problem or worry you have with this proposed approach that we can help you solve? If not, it's worth testing, and following up with a question specific to a bug or issue you discover as a result of that test.

Comment: My worry it this would be a viable way of doing it

Comment: What obstacle do you suspect would make it non-viable? [If you haven't found a specific obstacle, then the correct thing to do is to proceed until you demonstrate a concrete problem that you need help solving](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2808/39518).